# Speech imitation with different language?

Tags: python, neural-network

I want to train a neural network in Python which should be able to imitate the voice of a given person. I found [this Project](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning) on Github which seems quite good for my case.
The only problem is that the person I want to imitate the voice of is speaking Japanese.

I was wondering if it's possible to train a model on Japanese voice data and get it to speak English in some way. If it's pronouncing some words the false way it shouldn't be a problem for me to be honest.

P.S. In case you're wondering which voice should be cloned. I want to clone the voice of Shiina Mashiro from the Anime "Sakurasou no pet na kanojo".

Answer (score 0):

Personally I've worked at a very similar problem(btw using a module from the link). 
It's very **hard** to clone voice in good quality, you have to have a lot of records and use good preprocessing. And a powerful **GPU**.

The unexperienced user usually gets a "robotic" voice, the results sound very unnatural. If you type in google "voice clone app", you will find companies, which could help you(its just hint, not advertisement).

Comment: Thanks. I don't really expect totally realistic voice imitation at the beginning to be honest. I want to enhance the quality step by step. The main reason why I asked my question is: Are there problems with training on Japanese voice data and getting it to speak English?